# Is there a way to prevent Exchange server from reformatting my HTML messages?

Tags: html, transformation, exchange-server

I have a C# program that (among other things) creates HTML message bodies.  The messages have a little inline CSS and the tags have some style attributes.  As sent, the messages conform exactly to spec.

However, Exchange server performs a (brutal) transformation on all the CSS and formatting markup in an HTML message body, and pretty much re-writes all of it to its own "equivalent" format.  Mostly the results are in fact visually identical, but for some reason, certain formatting falls out in the translation - i.e. the conversion seems to be "correct but lossy".

We're using the standard Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage object.  Is there a way for the sender to suppress Exchange's translation behavior and just push through the original HTML?

Comment: sigh. I hate it when software thinks it knows better than you. MS software seems to be the king of this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer: use SMTP, not Exchange.